# Как обратится к элементу массива объектов?

Tags: java, массивы, объекты

Есть файл формата:

```
aaa;bbb;16.36;:
aaa;bbb;52.54;:
```

Разбивается на строки, разделителем `:`, далее разбивается на три строки разделителем `;`.

На основе этих данных пытаюсь создать объекты. Они помещаются в массив.

```
    package com.company;
 
public class Converter {
 
    public BillingObject[] toObject() throws Exception{
 
        ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile();
        String[] lines = readFile.GetLines(); // Массив строк
        BillingObject billingObject[] = new BillingObject[lines.length]; // Создает массив объектов длинной в количество строк в файле
 
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){                         //Проход на каждую строку
            String delims = "[;]";                                      //Разделитель
            String[] result = lines[i].split(delims);                   //Result получает 3 строки
            billingObject[i] = new BillingObject(result[0],result[1],Double.parseDouble(result[2])); //Новый объект в массив; разбитая строка передается конструктору
            //System.out.println(result[0] + " " + result[1] + " " + result[2]);
            //System.out.println(billingObject[i].getCode());
            //System.out.println(billingObject[i].getName());
            //System.out.println(billingObject[i].getPrice());
 
        }
        return billingObject; //Возвращается массив объектов
    }
```

В результате имеем массив объектов `billingObject`.

Не могу понять, как теперь работать с этими объектами из `main` или другого класса и как обращаться к значениям переменных и функциям типа `getPrice` имея массив?

```
    package com.company;

import javax.lang.model.type.ArrayType;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


       Converter converter = new Converter();

       Object[] arr = converter.toObject();


       System.out.println(arr[0]); // Выдает ссылку com.company.BillingObject@1b6d3586
       System.out.println(arr[1]); // Выдает ссылку com.company.BillingObject@4554617c


    }
```

Comment: `arr[0].getPrice()` или в цикле перебирая. в зависимости что нужно ............а что значит "как теперь работать с этими объектами из main или другого класса" ?

Comment: Конвертировать в BillingObject

Comment: У вас же метод `toObject()` возвращает массив `BillingObject`, а вы присваиваете результат переменной типа `Object[]`. 
Замените `Object[] arr = converter.toObject();`, на `BillingObject[] arr = converter.toObject();`

Answer (score 0):

```
BillingObject[] arr = new Converter().toObject();
for (BillingObject billingObject : arr.length) {
    System.out.println(billingObject.getPrice());
}
```

- так вы пройдетесь по всему массиву и получите поле прайс, которое выведется в консоль. если нужен только один элемент массива, например первый, то цикл замените на arr[1].getPrice().
- ну а если вы хотите, чтобы выводилась все поля класса BillingObject, но в этом классе переопределите метод toString.если не знаете, как это сделать, то выложите сюда класс BillingObject, чтобы можно было показать.

Comment: Код вызовет ошибку из-за того что `arr.length` (целое число) не итерируемый объект (не массив или список, например): https://ideone.com/rInrhe . Должно быть `for (BillingObject billingObject : arr)` : https://ideone.com/fmbNfH